# In my React JS project whenever I try to do npm install I get errors. Only when I use npm install --forceit works. How do I resolve all of them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-package

This is the error which I am getting

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.11.9
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers)
npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers)
npm ERR!   20 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.11.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"^5.11.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.11.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.11.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/varun/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/varun/.npm/_logs/2023-02-23T08_28_03_194Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried upgrading the versions of npm packages which I am using but still there are conflicts. I need them to be error free as it is going for production very soon. I don't want to use `npm install --force` always

Answer (score 0):

From npm version 7 `npm install` will fail when it encounters conflicting peer dependencies.

[Read more about this behaviour here](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/)

You can overcome this by using `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`.

`--force` sets different peer dependency version for conflicts

`--legacy-peer-deps` ignores peer dependencies

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
npm install --force
```